# 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

After running the Flutter project, I get this error. What can I do to solve it?

Error: `The method 'setMockMessageHandler' isn't defined for the class 'BasicMessageChannel<dynamic>'.`

I have tried:

`flutter pub upgrage`

and this is the result:

```
No dependencies changed.

1 package is discontinued.

76 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
```

also:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

did not help

Answer (score 0):

try repairing your cache, it worked for me

```
flutter pub cache repair
```